# How to get ServerAdmin email variable from httpd.conf

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, xampp, httpd.conf

How to get ServerAdmin email from httpd.conf in xampp
i have set

```
ServerAdmin test@gmail.com
```

in **`D:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf`**; but I don't not how to access ServerAdmin in php.

I want to use `ServerAdmin` email in my mail

```
$this->load->library('tes_email');
$this->test_email->from("test@gmail.com");
$this->test_email->to();//i don't know how to pass serverAdmin email in to
$this->test_email->subject("test test");
$this->test_email->message("test subject");
$this->test_email->send();
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is listed under the server environment variables attached to the key `SERVER_ADMIN`.

From the docs on [`$_SERVER` global variable](https://devdocs.io/php/reserved.variables.server):

> ### `'SERVER_ADMIN'`
>
> The value given to the `SERVER_ADMIN` (for Apache) directive in the
> web server configuration file. If the script is running on a virtual
> host, this will be the value defined for that virtual host.

Comment: The link is broken.